# killing an Oracle database session dangerous

Tags: oracle

I have inherited a database and every night i get buzzed in the middle of the night for locking issues.This database has severe locking issues and the usual drill is to bounce the application tier one by one so the locks get released . I am tired of doing this and came across a documentation where i can go ahead and kill the blocking session .

I am just wondering if i go ahead and kill the database blocking session after a session blocks for a time more then the predefined threshold

do i have the risk of corrupting the database ? 
if so how ?
Even if i assume that i am corrupting the database then restarting the application server also is equally risky and more painful for me too.

So what option do i choose here kill automatically the blocking session until the time the developer fixes the code that is causing the blocking ?

regards
Nick

Comment: You won't corrupt the database, per say, but killing the session will erase any non-committed changes that the session was working on. So just keep in mind you might end up ticking someone off or corrupting a batch process. Killing the session might take care of the immediate problem at hand but you should really take a look at your code to figure out why you are getting in deadlock situations to begin with.

Comment: Thanks DanK this is not a batch process but an OLTP kind of application i should have mentioned it.The application does an delete and then an insert and the delete blocks the insert and slowly it builds up until the app comes to a standstill

Comment: i agree with @DanK .. locks are there to stop you from doing stupid/unpredictable things like updating the same row as someone else.  killing the sessions doesnt really help it just changes the timing so it doesnt happen in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the exact purpose the Resource Manager directive MAX_IDLE_BLOCKER_TIME was created for.

[Example](https://deepakguptadba.wordpress.com/2008/07/09/automatic-killing-of-dead-lock-sessions/)

Answer (score 1):

No  , killing  a  session won't corrupt database as it will be rolled back and generate  UNDO , when you killed it , it gives the  "marked for kill " message,

do it the normal way "alter system kill session "sid, serial#' , not the "kill -9 .."